# GAE converting dictionary to NDB datastore entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, entity, app-engine-ndb

I would like to ask some guidelines on a small task that I am trying to solve.
I am experimenting with a small app that uses JSON data to save entities.

I know that you can easily convert a dict to an entity by just creating the model but, I am trying to build a more generic approach that would convert any dict to an entity.

My steps are:

1. Get the dict.
2. Validate that the dict keys correspond to an entitys model definitions by reading the class.**dict** of the model.
3. Try to unpack the validated properties in the model class contructor (create the model instance)
4. return it.

So far I am ok but lack of my python knowledge, is either constraining me, or confusing me.
Maybe I am as well forgetting or unaware of  more simple way to do it.

So here is it:

```
@classmethod
def entity_from_dict(cls, parent_key, dict):
    valid_properties = {}
    logging.info(cls.__dict__)
    for property,value in dict.iteritems():
        if property in cls.__dict__: # should  not iterate over functions, classmethods, and @property
            logging.info(cls.__dict__[property]) # this outputs eg: StringProperty('title', required=True)
            logging.info(type(cls.__dict__[property])) #this is more interesting <class 'google.appengine.ext.ndb.model.StringProperty'>
            valid_properties.update({property: value})
    # Update the id from the dict
    if 'id' in dict: # if not creating a new entity
            valid_properties['id'] = dict['id']
    # Add the parent
    valid_properties['parent'] = parent_key
    #logging.info(valid_properties)
    try:
        entity = cls(**valid_properties)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('Could not create entity \n' + repr(e))
        return False
    return entity
```

My problem is that I want only to validate ndb. Properties and not @classmethods, @property as well because this causes a conflict.

I am also using expando classes, so any property in the dict that is extra gets stored.

How can I check against these specific types?

Comment: Why aren't you using the populate() method  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_populate. In addition an instance lists all properties in `_properties`

Comment: @TimHoffman I guess I missed that. Trying now. Probably is what I need. Thanks and as I said I knew that I was missing something.

Comment: @TimHoffman the only problem that I still have is that because I am using expando models the extra dict keys-values get written at the datastore. Ass well as the classmethods and property create a colision if the same keys exist in the dict

Comment: OK, that's a bit of info you should have included.  Look at using _properties to drive the property iterator rather than the duct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it as @Tim Hoffman proposed using the `._properties` of the Ndb model. 
A thing I didn't know is that via the `._properties` I could get the model definition properties and I thought that it would only return the instance properties :-).

Also I did not use populate because I find that it does the same as passing the valid dict unpacked in the model's contructor ;-)

So here it is:

```
@classmethod
def entity_from_dict(cls, parent_key, data_dict):
    valid_properties = {}
    for cls_property in cls._properties:
        if cls_property in data_dict:
            valid_properties.update({cls_property: data_dict[cls_property]})
    #logging.info(valid_properties)
    # Update the id from the data_dict
    if 'id' in data_dict: # if creating a new entity
            valid_properties['id'] = data_dict['id']
    # Add the parent
    valid_properties['parent'] = parent_key
    try:
        entity = cls(**valid_properties)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('Could not create entity \n' + repr(e))
        return False
    return entity
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to override the `dict` keyword. Maybe replace it by something like data_dict?

Comment: This metot throws error when encounter an integer prop

Answer (score 1):

The JSON dump method in python which we using during the converting models to JSON for export converts non-strings into strings. Therefore Jimmy Kane methods throw the error due to model incompatibility. To avoid this problem I updated his method and added a method named `prop_literal` just for converting non-string characters which capsuled in the string into their literal type.

I also added the `entity.put()` to add the entity to datastore because the aim was that :)

```
def prop_literal(prop_type,prop_val):
    """
    Convert non-string encapsulated in the string into literal type
    """
    if "Integer" in prop_type:
        return int(prop_val)
    elif "Float" in prop_type:
        return float(prop_val)
    elif "DateTime" in prop_type:
        # bos gecsin neticede locale
        return None
    elif ("String" in prop_type) or ("Text" in prop_type):
        return prop_val
    elif "Bool" in prop_type:
        return True if prop_val == True else False
    else:
        return prop_val


def entity_from_dict(cls, parent_key, data_dict):
    valid_properties = {}
    for cls_property in cls._properties:
        if cls_property in data_dict:
            prop_type = str(cls._properties[cls_property])
            # logging.info(prop_type)
            real_val = prop_literal(prop_type,data_dict[cls_property])
            try:

                valid_properties.update({cls_property: real_val})
            except Exception as ex:
                # logging.info("Veri aktariminda hata:"+str(ex))
        else:
            # logging.info("prop skipped")
    #logging.info(valid_properties)
    # Update the id from the data_dict
    if 'id' in data_dict: # if creating a new entity
            valid_properties['id'] = data_dict['id']
    # Add the parent
    valid_properties['parent'] = parent_key
    try:
        entity = cls(**valid_properties)
        logging.info(entity)
        entity.put()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('Could not create entity \n' + repr(e))
        return False
    return entity
```